# Event handler reference from utility class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this method that I'm currently putting in each page I make, I know there should be a good way to move it to a single place for ease of maintenance and simplicity. I'm just not sure how I should handle the event handler. The event handler needs to be on each page, so how would I pass in a reference to the page properly so I can reference the event handler?

```
private void InsertLinkButton(string text, string id, UpdatePanel updateSummary)
    {
        LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
        link.Text = text;
        link.Click += new EventHandler(link_Click);   <------
        link.CausesValidation = false;
        AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
        trigger.ControlID = link.ID = "link" + id;
        trigger.EventName = "Click";
        Utils.Tag(link, placeHolderSummary);
        updateSummary.Triggers.Add(trigger);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just pass the event handler into your method as an argument?

```
private void InsertLinkButton(string text, string id, UpdatePanel updateSummary,
                              EventHandler clickHandler)
{
    LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
    link.Text = text;
    link.Click += clickhandler;
    ...
}
```

Call it with:

```
InsertLinkButton("text", "id", updatePanel, link_Click);
```

(Assuming `link_Click` is your method name.)

Comment: I knew it would be something simple like that... Feel so dumb

Answer (score 0):

I am not very in to ASP.NET, but I have done something relevant at Windows forms. I had a FormBase in which I had all the common functionality and from the derived I did whatever I wanted. I hooked up events and other things like authentication.